# Powershell is running at startup but not executing Remove-AppxPackage

Tags: powershell, startup, gpo

Executing a Powershell script at startup to strip out some of the bloat which comes with Windows 10.  It includes a check to see if it has already executed, which creates a flag file (so I know the script is running). However, the uninstall commands are not running (they run fine manually).

Hosts are running Windows 10 Pro. Script is being delivered via GPO; being applied ok as evidenced by the script running.

```
$DestinationFile = "C:\BloatFlag.txt"
if (Test-Path $DestinationFile) {

echo "Already Done"

} else {

Get-AppXPackage Microsoft.Microsoft3DViewer | Remove-AppXPackage
Get-AppXPackage DellInc.DellSupportAssistforPCs | Remove-AppXPackage
Get-AppXPackage DellInc.DellCommandUpdate | Remove-AppXPackage
# and the list goes on

echo "ONLY DELETE THIS FILE IF YOU REQUIRE TO RUN THE BLOAT REMOVAL SCRIPT AGAIN" > "C:\BloatFlag.txt"

}
```

- BloatFlag.txt is created when checking `C:\`.
- None of the listed software has been removed

I expected the apps would have been removed if the code reached creation of the text file.

Comment: If I remember correct `Remove-AppXPackage` works in user-enviroment on default. So ofc if you run it during Startup, it won't effect the user you log in afterwards.

Comment: Try using the `-AllUsers` switch: `... | Remove-AppXPackage -AllUsers`. ref.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/remove-appxpackage?view=win10-ps#optional-parameters

Comment: If you use @Paxz suggestion, you'll probably need to run the script with elevated permissions

Answer (score 0):

Maybe. Maybe not. Here is what I mean...

a) If `Get-AppXPackage` doesn't return anything, `Remove-AppXPackage` won't delete anything, and the marker file will still be created.

b) If either statement throws an exception, from what you've coded, that won't stop script execution and the marker file will be created. For example, stick the following in a file and run it. You'll see `Remove-AppXPackage` throw an exception, but `thinger.txt` still gets created.

```
Remove-AppXPackage xyz
write-output 'test' > thinger.txt
```

When the script executes during the boot/login/whatever process, does it run as the user who's app-packages are being removed, or does it run under a different user's context? If the latter, the user needs to be an admin (running under elevated permissions) to delete app-packages from another user's profile. if you're not sure, add a `whoami` to the output in the marker file you're creating.

Just a side note, I vaguely recall people `Remove-AppxPackage` and `Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage`. The first removed the package for a given local user. The second removes the package from the machine, so new users won't have the package installed. It wouldn't surprise me if you needed to run `Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage` with elevated permissions, but I don't see that in the cmdlet's documentation.

Comment: Thanks, this very much sent me down the right path.  Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage -AllUsers looping through an array   (sorry to repeat myself but between the two responses, I got where I needed to be)

Comment: That's fantastic! Why don't you post the solution to your problem in-case anyone finds this post pursuing an answer to the same question. Feel free to up-vote @js2010's answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove-Appxpackage is largely disabled these days, unless you want to do some sqlite database manipulation.  https://superuser.com/questions/1115801/unable-to-uninstall-universal-apps-through-powershell

Comment: Thanks, this very much sent me down the right path.  Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage -AllUsers looping through an array (sorry to repeat myself but between the two responses, I got where I needed to be)